# R plot if certain conditions are met

Tags: r, conditional-statements, scatter-plot

Hei,
I want to create a scatterplot of my data. I have a dataframe which includes (not only) the quartal of the year, the temperature, the precipitation and the gam_indices for a species as columns. 
Now I would like to plot the temperature (y) against the gam_index (x), but only if the quartal is 1.
So far I have the basic scatterplot-formula

```
plot(Archon_noduplicate$regional_gam, Archon_noduplicate$prev.temp, main="Archon_noduplicate",
 xlab="logAUC", ylab="prev.temp", pch=19)
```

but not really an idea about a short noice way to include the condition. Surely there would be a way to first create a new column which includes only the temperature-values for quartal one and then plot that, but as I have a lot of species and a lot of variables, it would be nice to find something less tedious.
My data, if you need some example, looks like this:

```
transect_id year day month      LST precipitation Quarter      SumPre average.temp  MinTemp  MaxTemp
    1       TR001 2011   1     1 15.70134      0.000000       1 161.9494290     14.69150 10.28747 18.95994
    2       TR001 2011  91     4 19.53845      1.858437       2 106.3809708     23.56554 16.58574 29.81955
    3       TR001 2011 182     7 28.96053      0.000000       3   0.9290609     29.62564 26.22075 31.78875
    4       TR001 2011 274    10 26.46966      0.000000       4  66.1280496     18.84587 12.18172 29.72368
    5       TR001 2012   1     1 13.17917      2.534553       1 154.5095844     13.38382 10.64767 17.80582
    6       TR001 2012  92     4 17.18347      0.000000       2   9.4365772     24.77507 17.18347 30.88236
      prev.temp prev.Precip          species regional_gam prop_pheno_sampled
    1  16.22194           0 Archon apollinus     1.780317          0.4154008
    2  24.81180           0 Archon apollinus     1.780317          0.4154008
    3  30.78058           0 Archon apollinus     1.780317          0.4154008
    4  22.72036           0 Archon apollinus     1.780317          0.4154008
    5  14.69150           0 Archon apollinus     1.103804          0.4413598
    6  23.56554           0 Archon apollinus     1.103804          0.4413598
```

I'm kind of stuck here so I'm thankful for any input!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
with(Archon_noduplicate[Archon_noduplicate$Quarter==1,], plot(regional_gam, prev.temp, main="Archon_noduplicate", xlab="logAUC", ylab="prev.temp", pch=19))
```